# Union multiple layers with OGRVRTUnionLayer

Tags: gdal, ogr, merge, overlay, union

I'm trying to union overlay layers using [OGRVRTUnionLayers](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html). However, it keeps the new records on new rows as opposed to appending the data to the same row (So you would expect to get back all data but with polygons intersected from the different layers). I would like that if I click on one polygon, it returns all the attributes for that union overlay polygon. Here is my code which is placing the data on seperate rows for each layer:

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="unionLayer">
        <OGRVRTLayer name="Layer1">
            <SrcDataSource>Layer1.shp</SrcDataSource>
            <SrcSQL>SELECT a FROM Layer1</SrcSQL>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="Layer2">
            <SrcDataSource>Layer2.shp</SrcDataSource>
            <SrcSQL>SELECT b FROM Layer2</SrcSQL>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
    </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

I would like it to do the same as the ArcGIS Union layer function.

Comment: Do you mean this process that ESRI calls as union http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm?

Comment: you can also try to get help on the mailinglist https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev

Comment: @user30184 - yes, I mean exactly that

Comment: @JakobMiksch thanks - I will ask there also

Comment: The OGRVRTUnion is is more of a database union operation, collecting rows from different datasets, rather than a spatial merge of rows based on overlapping geometries.